# How does IDA create COMMON, ABS and EXTERN segments of ELF-file?

Tags: ida, elf

Some symbols (from symbol table) in ELF-file belong to special sections (*COMMON*, *ABS*, *UNDEF*).

IDA creates virtual sections for this symbols.

**Subject**: What is the rule (or set of rules) which IDA use to create these special sections (start address, size, alignment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IDA's ELF-loader and some tests.

The order of sections in **REL-file**:

1. COMMON
2. ABS
3. EXTERN

The order of sections in **EXEC-file** (there is no COMMON section):

1. EXTERN
2. ABS

The **rules of section creation** are:

1. Take the adress after last real section
2. Calculate the size of each virtual section = `number_of_symbols * 4`
3. Create all needed virtual sections according to the right order
4. Fill all virtual sections with the corresponding symbols from symtab
5. Set *End*-address for each virtual section according to the real number of bytes (based on number of symbols in the section)